# Azure SQL Data Assets

Tags: sql, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

Currently I am going through the forced migration from Azure Machine Learning Studio Classic to the current version. I encountered an interesting outcome while migrating an Azure SQL DB "Data Asset".

Consider the following SQL query

```
SELECT 
  CAST([process_id] AS INT) AS process_id, 
  DATEDIFF(s, '1/1/1970 00:00:00',[timestamp]) AS [timestamp],
  [timestamp] as [abs_time],
  [brand] AS brand,
  CAST([measurement] AS INT) AS measurement,
  CAST([integrator_key] AS float) AS integrator_key,
  [status] AS status,
  DATEDIFF(s, '1/1/1970 00:00:00',[process_start_time]) AS process_start_time,
  CAST([target_measurement] AS INT) AS target
FROM DB_process_Data
ORDER BY process_id DESC, [timestamp]
```

This query executes all fine, however upon migrating this to azure machine learning studio NEW AWESOME MEGA edition this query fails with the following stack trace.

```
> Error: ScriptExecutionException was caused by DatabaseQueryException.
  'MSSQL' encountered exception of with error code '1033' while executing query 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT 
    CAST([process_id] AS INT) AS process_id, 
    DATEDIFF(s, '1/1/1970 00:00:00',[timestamp]) AS [timestamp],
    [timestamp] as [abs_time],
    [brand] AS brand,
    CAST([measurement] AS INT) AS measurement,
    CAST([integrator_key] AS float) AS integrator_key,
    [status] AS status,
    DATEDIFF(s, '1/1/1970 00:00:00',[process_start_time]) AS process_start_time,
    CAST([target_measurement] AS INT) AS target
FROM DB_process_Data
ORDER BY process_id DESC, [timestamp]) as subquery'. SqlException class: 15. HResult: x80131904.
    The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.
```

Is there anyway to mitigate this or get around this?
Removing the upfront forced order causes multiple downstream issues that I'd prefer to avoid.

Keep in mind I am adding these data assets in microsoft machine learning studio.

Comment: Now you might say ... well the error is right there you can't use an order by statement in a subquery, but that would miss the point. Why would my query be auto assigned to be a supquery in the form SELECT*FROM() in the first place???

Comment: Two answers I won't accept are the following

1. remove the order by statement and refactor subsequent or dependent workflows 
2. make an ordered table view on the SQL server side, this seems like bad practice and encourages lots of clutter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is AN answer to my question, although I think it's fairly hacky.

```
SELECT top (SELECT count(processid) FROM [dbo].[DB_Process_Data])
    CAST([processid] AS INT) AS processid, 
    DATEDIFF(s, '1/1/1970 00:00:00',[timestamp]) AS [timestamp],
    [timestamp] as [abs_time],
    [brand] AS brand,
    CAST([measurement] AS INT) AS measurement,
    CAST([integrator_key] AS float) AS integrator_key,
    [status] AS status,
    DATEDIFF(s, '1/1/1970 00:00:00',[process_start_time]) AS process_start_time,
    CAST([target_measurement] AS INT) AS target
  FROM [dbo].[DB_Process_Data]
order by processid desc, timestamp
```